# MySQL trigger - exit handler not found with SELECT INTO / SET _ = SELECT

Tags: mysql, triggers, handler

I've got a MariaDB trigger (before insert) with this piece of code inside:

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR
        NOT FOUND
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Aucun véhicule possible.'
        ;

        SET NEW.id_vehicule = (
        SELECT id        
        FROM vehicule
        WHERE date_mise_service <= DATE(NEW.date_heure_depart_planifie)
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
        );
END;
```

But the NOT FOUND handler is never firing, whenever there's an 'id' matching the SELECT request or not.

However, if I change this to that:

```
BEGIN
        DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR
        NOT FOUND
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Aucun véhicule possible.'
        ;

        SELECT id
        INTO v_id_vehicule
        FROM vehicule
        WHERE date_mise_service <= DATE(NEW.date_heure_depart_planifie)
        ORDER BY RAND()
        LIMIT 1
        ;

        SET NEW.id_vehicule = v_id_vehicule;
END;
```

Then everything's working fine, and the handler is firing if no matching id is found.

I don't get it: is this about SELECT INTO working fine with handlers and SET x = SELECT not working?

Or the NEW.field ?

Am I misunderstanding something?

Thanks!

Comment: Signal for NOT FOUND is generated only when the whole query output is empty. In your trigger the empty rowset may be produced by the subquery only which does not produce NOT FOUND event. Divide your query to `SELECT INTO variable` and further `SET column = variable`.

Comment: I do understand now why the signal wasn't generated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To set to null even if empty set

```sql
        SELECT id
        INTO v_id_vehicule
        FROM (
          ( 
            SELECT id
            FROM vehicule
            WHERE date_mise_service <= DATE(NEW.date_heure_depart_planifie)
            ORDER BY RAND()
            LIMIT 1
          ) 
          UNION ALL 
          ( SELECT NULL )
          LIMIT 1
       ) v
```